# Will it work if I put two e-markers on both side of USB-C cable

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

One of connectors on my USB-C charging cable is broken. It's a 5A cable with a e-marker that has 6 pins, D+/-, CC/VConn, VBUS+/-. I want to replace the broken connector but I'm not sure whether it's the e-marker side or the dumb side.

What if I put on a new e-marker connector anyway? Will the two e-marker chips interfere with each other because they are both on the CC line?

Comment: Two chips will interfere. Just buy a new cable.